# What's the difference between the Sony Ericsson Xperia Active ST17i, the ST17i-BKW, ST17a, and the ST17a-BKO?

Tags: sony-xperia-active

I am interested in buying Sony Ericcson Xperia Active (unlocked) but there are several choices and I can't figure out which phone is which. Can someone explain to me the difference? Thanks!

Comment: http://talk.sonymobile.com/thread/45643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a is for 'americas' i is 'international' e.g. the rest of the world.  You get slightly different network support.

ST17i UMTS HSPA 900 (Band VIII), 2100 (Band I)
GSM GPRS/EDGE 850, 900, 1800, 1900

ST17a UMTS HSPA 800 (Band V), 1900 (Band II), 2100 (Band I)
GSM GPRS/EDGE 850, 900, 1800, 1900

This is from [the whitepaper.](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/st17/whitepaper_EN_st17_xperia_active.pdf)

I belive everything else about the phone is the same.

BKW and BKO I think will be the colour scheme of an orange or white hilight.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK not much other than the [frequency bands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_frequency_bands) they operate on:

**ST17i:** (i = International version) Dual-band

UMTS HSPA 900 (Band VIII), 2100 (Band I)

GSM GPRS/EDGE 850, 900, 1800, 1900

**ST17a:** (a = American version) Tri-band

UMTS HSPA 800 (Band V), 1900 (Band II), 2100 (Band I)

GSM GPRS/EDGE 850, 900, 1800, 1900